# Murphy's Law applied to Internet Security

Tags: security, phishing

I'm a fanatic of Murphy's Law and I have it in mind at programming time. There are a lot of "applied" versions in a variety of fields. Maybe (as stack overflow users) we can compile a list of them **applied to Internet Security**. I suggest this because in times of phishing, XSS, CSRF and a lot more of treats surrounding the programmer and the users it would be a good idea to have a list of what to expect in order to keep track of possible vulnerabilities in your apps and systems.

An example would be: 
"Vulnerabilities appears spontaneously but they don't disappear in the same way".

Please show your ideas about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you SnOrfus, but Murphy's Law is related with anything that can go wrong, and as I see your code never fails.

Comment: On the contrary, my code fails often, and when my code fails, I seek to solve the problem at hand... not give it a catchy tag-line.

Comment: There are not "catchy tag-lines", there are just reminders that give us some humility.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only truly secure system is one that is powered off, cast in a block of concrete and sealed in a lead-lined room with armed guards - and even then I have my doubts.

-- Eugene H. Spafford

Answer (score 5):

Your security system will successfully prevent you from following up on what the crackers did.

Answer (score 4):

The best way past a pesky security feature is a 13-year-old.

Answer (score 3):

Impenetrable security isn't.

Answer (score 2):

"Any time you encounter a security hole, you can only find more."

Answer (score 2):

The more you ask professionals, the more you have security holes.

Answer (score 0):

"Expect the unexpected."  (Richie ducks 8-)

Answer (score 0):

This is one I have found today:

An **"unbreakable"** security solution is recognized because once it's broken it lets the system completely open and vulnerable.